# Is there any way to install Windows 8 without touching Ubuntu partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Recently I bought too many Windows games so I decided to get back my Windows 8 just for fun. But then I discovered that it can't be installed into Ubuntu partitions since they're not NTFS and the only way is to delete those partitions if I want to install Windows. Of course I could delete those, install Windows and then reinstall Ubuntu, but I don't want to lose all my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could resize Ubuntu's partitions from a Live CD/USB using gParted and then install Windows in the free space.

Windows will likely munch Ubuntu's bootloader, which you'll need to reinstall after installing Windows, again from the Live CD or USB. This is covered in the documentation here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows